# How to switch one attribute value from other attribute value of a same element and remove first attribute

Tags: jquery

Is there any way to minimize these piece of code, So we can write in a single line

Basically I want to switch the attribute value of data-original to src and then want to remove data-original attribute from the element. Below is my code which is working for me but i want to minimize these piece of code so I can write in single Line.

```
if($('#pop-slider li:eq(nth)').find('img').attr('data-original')){
    var cureSrc = $('#pop-slider li:eq(nth)').find('img').attr('data-original');
        $('#pop-slider li:eq(nth)').find('img').attr('src',cureSrc);
        $('#pop-slider li:eq(nth)').find('img').removeAttr('data-original');
}
```

Comment: You could chain the functions. `.attr(...).removeAttr(...)`

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Satpal Not necessarily. OP is looking for a specific solution to a specific problem. On Code Review, the result may very well be a longer line of code for readability purposes.

Answer (score 1):

i think you can use following code:

```
$('#pop-slider li:eq(nth)').find('img[data-original]').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src',$(this).attr('data-original')).removeAttr('data-original')
});
```

Comment: I don't want to replace for all element having`(img[data-original)`.

Comment: @JitendraYadav According your code, you select `$('#pop-slider li:eq(nth)')` then find descendant `img` that has `attr('data-original')` and then change it's attribute. Did i get it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
var img=$('#pop-slider li:eq(nth)').find('img');
if(img.attr('data-original')){
        img.attr('src',img.attr('data-original'));
        img.removeAttr('data-original');
}
```